# How to make POST request by curl with an array of a map for actix-from-data?

Tags: rust, rust-actix

I'm attempting to send POST request by curl with an array of map. How it should be written?

I wrote:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F files[]="name=\"qqq\"" localhost:8080/upload`

But it returns a `Found field with unexpected name or type` error.

By the way, How it would be with uncommented stroke with two fields in each map? for file's name and for file's data ?

```
fn main() -> Result<(), failure::Error> {
    let form = Form::new()
        .field("files", Field::array(
            Field::map()
                .field("name", Field::text())
    //                .field("file", Field::file(Gen))
                .finalize()
        ));

    println!("{:?}", form);

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .service(resource("/upload")
                .data(form.clone())
                .route(post()
                    .to(upload_multipart)
                )
            )
    })
    .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
    .run()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl -i -X POST -F files[][name]="qqq" localhost:8080/upload`

proper command